# Store process object in database

Tags: java, persistence

I am doing

```
Process p = null;
        if(CheckOS.isWindows())
            p = rt.exec(filebase+port+"/hlds.exe +maxplayers "+players+ " -game cstrike -console +port "+port+" -nojoy -noipx -heapsize 250000 +map de_dust2 +servercfgfile server.cfg +lservercfgfile +mapcyclefile mapcycle.txt +motdfile motd.txt +logsdir logs -zone 2048",null,  new File(filebase+port)) ;
```

and want to store `p` in database but process is not serializable, how to save it in database??

and can we check if process `p` is still running or died due to some crash or something

Comment: What does it mean to store a Process in the database? A Process instance is associated with an honest-to-goodness process at the operating system level... Are you trying to keep a reference to a process in a web session or something like that? To summarize, what is this usecase?

Comment: actually i will be checking whether the process is running or not after some interval of time, so want to save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely cannot store a Process itself in a database. But if you are trying to keep processes around for future use (within the scope of the VM), then you can have something like this:

```
public class ProcessRegistry {

  public static class Key {}

  private static final ProcessRegistry INSTANCE = new ProcessRegistry();

  public static ProcessRegistry getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

  private final Map<Object, Process> _processes = new HashMap<...>();

  public Key registry(Process p) {
    Key key = new Object();
    _processes.put(key, p);
    return key;
  }

  public Process lookup(Key key) {
    return _processes.get(key);
  }
}
```

You can store and lookup from wherever (within the confines of your classloader) using

```
ProcessRegistry.getInstance().register(...)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to save a process to a database. Instead you can save a reference to it in the database. If I was doing it I would do:

1. Create a new process
2. Save the process to a map with some id
3. Save that id to database

When looking it up you can look up the process with an id to see if it has ended.

Comment: I was also thinking you can spawn a new thread that reads the output and has that ready for you when you want.